# Выравнивание по вертикали с помощью доп. элемента

Tags: css, выравнивание

Существует способ выровнять inline-block элемент по вертикали с помощью доп. элемента. Пример http://jsfiddle.net/k46mm5ve/29/

```
div {
  height: 200px;
  background: #FAF375;
  text-align: center;
}
div:before{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height:100%;
}

span {
  font-size: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green; 
  width: 60%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Почему это работает? Хотелось бы опровержение или подтверждение своих мыслей.
Все строчные выравниваются через `vertical-align` по середине `x-height`. Значит нам нужно эту `x-height` поставить по центру родительского элемента.  Для этого надо назначить дочернему высоту = высоте родительского. Мы не можем нашему дочернему поставить такую высоту, ведь он нам нужен не на весь родительский. Тогда мы используем доп. элемент. Он невидим, если мы, проставим для него только высоту. Но он делает строку = родительской строке. И все элементы в строке выравниваются как надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строчные блоки при применении `line-height` выравниваются по вертикали относительно соседних блоков, а в вашем случае блок всего один. Потому для того, чтобы выровнять с использованием этого свойства, необходимо добавить блок, относительно которого и будет происходить выравнивание. А для того, чтобы он не мешал, его создают псевдоэлементом (не нарушает семантику и внутреннюю структуру) и дают ему высоту равную высоте родителя.

Comment: Спасибо, поняла.

Comment: Хотя,  наверное точнее так  -  строчные блоки выравниваются не относительно друг-друга, а все оказывают влияние на базовую линию. Так мы через дополнительный элемент ее смещаем, тем самым смещая исходный дочерний элемент.